# How to get file modification date asynchronously in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, file, asynchronous

I am trying to poll a file to check if it has been modified or deleted on disk. 

In case of slow network if I use the File `exists` or `modificationDate` properties, the application will hang.

Is there a way to do it asynchronously?

Sample

```
var f:File = new File(url);
if (f.exists && f.modificationDate.getTime() > oldModificationDate) { // hangs on both exists and modificationDate calls
    // File changed on disk
    ...
```

Thanks for any help,
Paolo

Comment: If targeting flash 11.4 you could use an 'actionscript worker', which is essentially a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but workers are not available on our version.

Comment: You can also try work with native process and use some external code .

Comment: We use Adobe Air to run on multuple platforms. It would be better to avoid native processes. Maybe the exists can be achieved using async directory listing of parent folder, but for modificationDate I'm in total dark...

Comment: Could you show your code and mark place there it hangs?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit hacky, but what about using getDirectoryListingAsync()? You could create a temporary File object that points to the directory where the file you want is located. When the asynchronous handler is called, you can loop through the results until you find a file that matches your target and then do your date checking. Something like this:

```
var expectedName:String = "myFile";
var oldModificationDate:Date=new Date();

public function fileCheck(fileName:String)
{
File file = new File(fileName);
File dir = new File("/somefiles/localDir/");
dir.getDirectoryListingAsync();
dir.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, directoryListingHandler);
}

function directoryListingHandler(event:FileListEvent):void {
    var list:Array = event.files;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i].name==expectedName && f.modificationDate.getTime() > oldModificationDate)
          {
            fileFoundHandler();
          }
    }
}

function fileFoundHandler():void
{
  //your response code goes here
}
```